Webpack + docker + hot reload 404 page not found
I am trying to get successful hot reload behavior using react + webpack5 + docker.
I have tried many ways. The main difference was noticed with “writeToDisk” option. If it is false, my /app/dist inside the container becomes empty after hot reload, and the page is now 404 page not found. If option is true, then new files appear in dist, postfixed by hot-reload. But there is no change on the page.
I am not good at devops things, please help.
Here are my configs:
compose.yml
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - frontend-dist:/app/frontend-build
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - GIN_MODE=release
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - frontend

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - frontend-dist:/app/dist
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    command: ['pnpm', 'run', 'dev']

volumes:
  frontend-dist:

webpack.config.js
import * as path from "path";

import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);


export default {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/main.tsx"],
  output: {
      publicPath: '/',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "[name].[hash].js"
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    devMiddleware: {
      // writeToDisk: true,
      // publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    hot: true,

  },    
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 500,
    poll: 1000
  },
  plugins: [ 
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({ template: "./index.html", inject: true }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    new StylelintPlugin()
  ],

Dockerfile (front)
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN corepack enable
RUN pnpm install

COPY . .
RUN pnpm run build


One of Docker's main goals is to isolated the container from the host filesystem, and trying to work around this for a hot-reload environment seems to often have problems.  Can you just remove Docker from this stack?  The volumes: blocks in the Compose file are wrong, a named volume as you have it ignores both the host system content and also ignores any updates if you rebuild the image.
